# Send row by row without duplicates

Tags: c#

I have the following table

[image]

As you can see there is a column called Integration of type bool, all this table is shown in a DataGridView through a stored procedure that is this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Payments]
AS 
SELECT 'CE-'+CardCode AS CardCode,DocType,Series,DocDate,dbo.udf_GetNumeric(DocNum) AS DocNum,
DocEntry,TrsfrAcct,TrsfrDate,TrsfrSum, Integration,Comments,SumApplied
FROM  PaymentsReceived WHERE Integration = 0
```

This SP says to only show me those that are at 0 which is false, what I do with those that are false is to send them through a web service, I have a method that goes through each row and sends it every time it does a send sets it to true, then it disappears from the DataGridView, this method is inside a timer that fires every 5 seconds, in this method there is a condition that says if the Integration is == false, let it send, this is the method.

```
private async void Envio_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ProxyBL proxy = new ProxyBL();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow Datos in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    PagosRecibidos pagos = new PagosRecibidos
                    {
                        CardCode = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[0].Value),
                        DocType = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[1].Value),
                        Series = Convert.ToInt32(Datos.Cells[2].Value),
                        DocDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Datos.Cells[3].Value),
                        DocEntry = Convert.ToInt32(Datos.Cells[5].Value),
                        TrsfrAcct = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[6].Value),
                        TrsfrDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Datos.Cells[7].Value),
                        TrsfrSum = Convert.ToDecimal(Datos.Cells[8].Value),
                        Integration = Convert.ToBoolean(Datos.Cells[9].Value),
                        Comments = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[10].Value),
                        SumApplied = Convert.ToDecimal(Datos.Cells[11].Value)
                    };
                    Inte = pagos.Integration;
                    if (Inte == false)
                    {
                        var EnvioDatos = await proxy.EnviarPago(pagos);
                    }
                    ListarEmple();
                    ListarLog();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is the method where SendPayment comes in

This method I get the response from Services, where if the operation was successful or failed, it inserts this in a Log

```
Consultas c = new Consultas();

        public async Task<string> EnviarPago(PagosRecibidos detalle)
        {
            try
            {
                ProxyXML xmlProxy = new ProxyXML();
                string respuesta = await xmlProxy.EnviarSAP(detalle);
                c.InsertarLog(1, DateTime.Now, respuesta, xmlProxy.XmlSerializado);
                return respuesta;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

After this method, enter the shipment, EnviaSAP

Which is where I capture the answer, if the operation was successful then give me the Integration column as "1 true"

```
readonly Consultas c = new Consultas();  
        public string XmlSerializado = null;

    public async Task<string> EnviarSAP(PagosRecibidos detalle)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WSSincronizacionClient clienteSAP = new WSSincronizacionClient())
            {
                XmlSerializado = this.SerializarXml(detalle);
                var respuesta = await clienteSAP.EnviarDatosSAPAsync(XmlSerializado);
                if (respuesta.Contains("true|Operación Exitosa|"))
                {
                    c.EditarIntegration(true, Convert.ToInt32(detalle.DocEntry));
                }
                return respuesta;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Everything works correctly but when sending it, sometimes it sends it double or duplicate, that is, in SAP it arrives twice, how can I do this validation, that the one that is false only enters me once, that it does not send it for any reason twice , and in which part should I do this validation

I also don't know why if you already have that validation that I only sent the fake ones, you still send it twice.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that the time to process an individual row exceeds the timer interval, therefore you might be iterating over the same item in two handler calls in parallel, because there isn't enough time for the other handler to complete its processing.

Maybe you could flag the row when you're fetching it, and save the changes so that flag could act as a discriminator for other timer tick handler calls to ignore the row:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Datos in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var alreadyProcessingRow = Convert.ToBoolean(Datos.Cells[{ProcessingFlagColumnIndex}].Value);
    if(alreadyProcessingRow)
        continue; //skip the row, don't reprocess it

    Datos.Cells[{ProcessingFlagColumnIndex}] = true; //Mark the row as processing

    PagosRecibidos pagos = new PagosRecibidos
    {
        CardCode = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[0].Value),
        DocType = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[1].Value),
        Series = Convert.ToInt32(Datos.Cells[2].Value),
        DocDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Datos.Cells[3].Value),
        DocEntry = Convert.ToInt32(Datos.Cells[5].Value),
        TrsfrAcct = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[6].Value),
        TrsfrDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Datos.Cells[7].Value),
        TrsfrSum = Convert.ToDecimal(Datos.Cells[8].Value),
        Integration = Convert.ToBoolean(Datos.Cells[9].Value),
        Comments = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[10].Value),
        SumApplied = Convert.ToDecimal(Datos.Cells[11].Value)
    };
    Inte = pagos.Integration;
    if (Inte == false)
    {
        var EnvioDatos = await proxy.EnviarPago(pagos);
    }
    Datos.Cells[{ProcessingFlagColumnIndex}] = false; //reset the flag (not that important if you just don't care after processing)
    ListarEmple();
    ListarLog();
}
```

I'm not really sure if you can do that with that datagridview object, but in case you couldn't you could use something like a ConcurrentDictionary, and store the rows (or row Ids) you are currently processing there in order to check and avoid duplicate processing.